# How to get Selected item id with bootstrap typeahead

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am receiving the following JSON from back end.

```
[{"video_name":"video1","video_id":"74"},{"video_name":"videoactual","video_id":"89"}]
```

I am using bootstrap type ahead for autocomplete purpose

This is my code

Currently on selection i am able to get the video name

How can i get the selected video id  ??

```
var videoNames = new Array();
var videoIds = new Object();
$('#linkvideoname').typeahead({


 updater: function(selection){
        alert("You selected: " + selection)
    },

    source: function(query, process) {
     $.ajax({
        url: url + '/videodetails',
            dataType: "json",
              data: query,
               contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            type: "POST",
           success: function(data) {
                 $.each( data, function ( index, video )
            {
                videoNames.push( video.video_name );
                videoIds[video.name] = video.video_id;
            } );
                  process(videoNames);

            }
        });
    },
});
```